# Strange error coming up whenever I try to install/run any application that deals with Network in some/other way

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, permissions, dll

As I laid out in the question title, I am getting the below error whenever I attempt to install (or run executable of) any software that deals with Network / Internet(maybe for firing HTTPS connections ?) in some way:
[image]

I tried installing and running `Internet Download Manager(IDM)` and `Anydesk` applications from fresh source files, and I know that some while ago these were easily getting installed and executed on-user-demand, but now this error shows up when trying to run `Anydesk`/`IDM`, so it's not related to these softwares but with OS.

I confess that I did try to change permissions and access control of `%SystemRoot%\Temp` folder and then perhaps went too far and ran delete command on it's files, but I am sure I didn't deleted unpermitted ones(ones that are in use by process(es)).

Then how could such a weird and unusual error crept in ?? Moreover how do I resolve this in proper way without needing to format-and-reinstall-Win10 ?

Comment: Run in a Command Prompt run as Admin the command `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth ` and  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc Running the `.../RestoreHealth` command, after 54.6% completion, it says `Error 1392 - The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.` What to do now ?

Comment: Now at this point, you need to do a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link    https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows setup is corrupted.

To try a set it to a known state -
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
This is the same as doing a major Windows update, so take backups.

On the chance that this corruption was caused by a virus,
when Windows becomes functional again run some deep antivirus scans
using only well-known products.
If an infection is found, see the post
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

If this doesn't help, you may need to reinstall Windows.